# cross_val_score and StratifiedKFold give different result

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

Here is code for `StratifiedKFold` with loop

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=2020)
for train_idx, val_idx in kfold.split(train,labels):
  x_train,y_train=train[train_idx],labels[train_idx]
  x_val,y_val=train[val_idx],labels[val_idx]

  count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
  count_vectorizer.fit(x_train)
  X_train_cv = count_vectorizer.transform(x_train)
  X_val_cv  = count_vectorizer.transform(x_val)

  cv_classifier = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',C=25,max_iter=500)
  cv_classifier.fit(X_train_cv, y_train)
  y_pred = cv_classifier.predict(X_val_cv)
  f1=f1_score(y_val, y_pred,average='macro')
  print(f1)
```

Result i got is

```
0.49
0.46
0.48
0.48
0.50
```

Following the `cross_val_score` code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
cv_classifier = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',C=25,max_iter=500,class_weight='balance')
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
count_vectorizer.fit(train)
train_cv = count_vectorizer.transform(train)
print(cross_val_score(cv_classifier,train_cv, labels, cv=StratifiedKFold(5,shuffle = True),scoring='f1_macro'))
```

Result I got is

```
0.70 0.74 0.70 0.734 0.679
```

**EIDT**
I added `pipeline`

```
cv_classifier = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',C=25,max_iter=500,class_weight='balance')
classifier_pipeline = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), cv_classifier)

print(cross_val_score(classifier_pipeline,train, labels, cv=StratifiedKFold(5,shuffle = True),scoring='f1_macro'))
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for better results in the 2nd case is that the train_cv dataset has already been fitted and transformed by the `count_vectorizer`.

In the former case, within each CV fold, you fit the vectorizer on the training data and transform the validation data. This is the correct approach because the vectorizer does not see the validation data during fit.

In order to do the same with the `cross_val_score()`, you should create a [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) that contains both the vectorizer and the logistic regression model. Then, you pass this pipeline to the `cross_val_score()` while the data should the initial `train` dataset (not the `train_cv` one).

Comment: i added pipeline, check the post please, but result did not match

Comment: I see that in the pipeline, the logistic model has `class_weight='balance'` while this is not specified in the manual loop.  Also can you set the same random_state in both cases?

Answer (score 2):

you need to set the random seed here `cv=StratifiedKFold(5,shuffle = True)` as well or give the same `kfold` for `cross_val_score`.

I have created a toy example for your workflow.

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
import numpy as np

categories = ['alt.atheism', 'talk.religion.misc']
newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train',
                                      categories=categories)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

train, labels = np.array(newsgroups_train.data), newsgroups_train.target


kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=2020)
for train_idx, val_idx in kfold.split(train, labels):
    x_train, y_train = train[train_idx], labels[train_idx]
    x_val, y_val = train[val_idx], labels[val_idx]

    count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
    count_vectorizer.fit(x_train)
    X_train_cv = count_vectorizer.transform(x_train)
    X_val_cv = count_vectorizer.transform(x_val)

    cv_classifier = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', C=25, max_iter=500)
    cv_classifier.fit(X_train_cv, y_train)
    y_pred = cv_classifier.predict(X_val_cv)
    f1 = f1_score(y_val, y_pred, average='macro')
    print(f1)

cv_classifier = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs',C=25,max_iter=500,class_weight='balance') 
classifier_pipeline = make_pipeline(CountVectorizer(), cv_classifier) 
print(cross_val_score(classifier_pipeline,train, labels, cv=kfold,scoring='f1_macro'))
```

output:

```
0.9059466848940533
0.9527147766323024
0.9174937965260546
0.9336297237218165
0.9526315789473685
[0.90594668 0.95271478 0.9174938  0.93362972 0.95263158]
```

Comment: you provide an excellent toy example. i added the same kfold, but result did not match. i think there is an issue with manual for loop kfold... not with `cross_val_score`, because result obtained from `StratifiedKFold` did not match with `train_test_split`

Comment: surprising! When you provide same `kfold`, the results should match exactly. can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: can you please check this [colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RM4Lm927d_IE6uJAu77Zpglu7_Rik3gh)

Comment: looks like you have added `class_weight='balance'` in `cross_val_score`?

Comment: i added in both, but same issue, check the update  [colab file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RM4Lm927d_IE6uJAu77Zpglu7_Rik3gh)